# Drawing rectangles on two different JPanels then adding JPanels on JFrame

Tags: java

I want to draw two rectangles on two different JPanels and then I want to add both the JPanels on JFrame simultaneously. Please tell how I can do that?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to draw two rectangles on two different JPanels

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for working examples of custom painting. The key is to override the `getPreferredSize()` method to return the size of the panel containing the rectangle.

> I want to add both the JPanels on JFrame

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Layout Manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html). You then just add the panels to the frame like any other Swing component.

The real question is why do you want two panels? Just draw the two Rectangles on the same panel. See [Playing With Shapes](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/05/13/playing-with-shapes/) for more ideas on how to do this type of painting.

Comment: please give an example explaining my question

Comment: I did give examples. The tutorial has an example of how to create a component with custom painting. Start with the code from the tutorial and customize the painting code to do what you want. If you need more help than you need to post the example code you have written that demonstrates the problems you are having.